# Autobiographer Badge rewarded on so

Tags: support, badges, profile-page

Just got the [Autobiographer badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/9/autobiographer). The info says "Completed "About Me" section of user profile.". Iirc I wrote the "About Me" section back in 2012, and after reviewing other people with that badge, I noticed that a lot got them today (or in the last 12h).

Did something change with that badge?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The criteria for the Autobiographer badge have changed and the badge is being awarded retroactively, in batches.

You only need to fill in About Me now to qualify, where before you had to fill out almost all fields in your profile. You now qualify for the badge, so the batch process awarded you one.

See ["Autobiographer" Badge now only requires sharing what YOU want with the community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239938/autobiographer-badge-now-only-requires-sharing-what-you-want-with-the-communit?cb=1)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Searched here, didn't find anything and totally forgot about the split.

Comment: @nietonfir: the link is featured, so it shows up on Stack Overflow in the community bulletin. Unfortunately, the Meta.SO bulletin does not include the Meta.SE featured posts.